# Detecting operating system or computer name through a Java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, operating-system, detection

I have a Java web app that I develop on a Windows machine and will deploy on a Unix machine.

There are some file path settings and permissions details that differ on the two (and there is nothing I can do to change this). Is there some way of detecting which machine the app is sitting on (it's only one of two), either by detecting the operating system or the computer's name so I can then using the appropriate settings.

Comment: Hi Ankur! This is the 10th time or so that you *created* the `servlet` tag while you are supposed to use the `servlets` tag (with the `s`). I've edited it everytime and commented the edit in line of "Please choose tags carefully, there is a `servlets` tag in the list with more than 1000 questions". You should have seen this if you have read the revisions tab in your history. But as far now you seem to ignore that or not to understand that. So here's a comment to "wake up" you: **Choose tags carefully!** ;)

Comment: Ok thanks I had not realised I was doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Computer name and OS name are two different properties to get computer name use

```
String computername=InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
      System.out.println(computername);
```

and to get os name use

```
java.lang.System.getProperty("os.name")
```

Abdul Khaliq

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
java.lang.System.getProperty("os.name")
```

to know the operating system name.

Get more info at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html.

Answer (score 2):

Check this: http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/OSInformation.shtml

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.getProperty("os.name")`